# Do I have the private keys to CAs installed on my browser?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, key-exchange

Could someone please help explain the following comment from [Why was the private key of the Superfish certificate so easily extractable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82113/why-was-the-private-key-of-the-superfish-certificate-so-easily-extractable#)

> [The main issue with private key extraction is the use of the same root
>   certificate on each install. It should be autogenerated (Fiddler does
>   it) so the private key is specific to your computer.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82113/why-was-the-private-key-of-the-superfish-certificate-so-easily-extractable#comment135239_82115)

I am researching the Lenovo SuperFish adware and I had originally thought our browsers only have a copy of the public keys of each installed CA - do we also have a personalized unique private key associated with each CA public key installed?

Comment: No. You only have public part of CAs certs in your browser while the private key is always secret and well guarded.

Comment: If you read the rest of the answers, they do a good job explaining this. A self-signed cert was used.

Comment: (@Aria) CA privatekey _should_ be restricted and guarded; the big problem with Superfish (beyond an OEM installing an interceptor in the first place) is that all copies of Superfish used the same privatekey and thus reverse-engineering one copy allowed deceiving all the other systems.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, and I could be wrong, This is because it was using self signed certs that were generated psuedo on-the-fly.
Because of this, if you reverse engineer the interception mechanism you could extract the private key